# How to set Content-Type in Azure Data Factory Copy Activity?

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a Data factory pipeline that copies data from one container to another (ADLS Gen 2 for both). I am using the Copy activity with the following settings:

[Source settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VHOT.png) & [Sink settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fRdF.png)

In the source the Content-Type is correctly set to application/json. However, when the data is copied to the sink, the Content-Type is changed to application/octet-stream. This causes some trouble when for instance reading the blob in a Logic App as it expects the type to be json. I do not find anywhere to send in the Content-Type in the Copy activity.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

As I am using a JSON dataset and copying between two blob containers (ADLS Gen 2), I do not seem to have the "preserve" option as you can see in this screenshot below:
[image: Settings for my dataset.]

Comment: Please have a try this. Add ```"preserve": ["Attributes"]``` as [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-preserve-metadata#preserve-metadata) shows.

Comment: I can't seem to find that setting? It seems that it is only available for binary format datasets? Mine is defined as a JSON dataset.

Comment: It seems that there is no `Preserve` option in Setting. You can click `{}` button and directly add it to your  script code.  Maybe it can work.

Comment: Have the same issue was wondering if you found a solution to the problem?

Comment: No I did not find any solution, I ended up using a Logic app for the task, and in there it is possible to set the Content-Type.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment you can use preserve Attributes which is in the settings of the copy activity.

[image: Preserve option in Settings]

Comment: I do not have the "Preserve" option in my settings. I've updated my question with a screenshot from my settings tab.